# for loop returning the last object not the preceding ones python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
def excel(vendor_ids):
    for i in vendor_ids:
        t = Test()
        c = pycurl.Curl()
        c.setopt(c.URL, (str("https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/%s")%(i)))
        c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer %s'%(access_token)])
        c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, t.body_callback)
        c.perform()
        c.close()
        contents=(t.contents)
        #print(contents)
        jsondict=(json.JSONDecoder().decode(contents))
        collect=(jsondict['item_collection'])
        ids= (collect['entries'])
        dic=[]
        for k in ids:
            print(k)
            return k 


K=excel(vendor_ids)
```

when i print the following print but when i return i only get the last one

```
{u'sequence_id': u'0', u'etag': u'0', u'type': u'folder', u'id': u'4322345554', u'name': u'rejected'}
{u'sequence_id': u'0', u'etag': u'0', u'type': u'folder', u'id': u'4392281882', u'name': u'incoming'}
{u'sequence_id': u'0', u'etag': u'0', u'type': u'folder', u'id': u'4392284514', u'name': u'rejected'}
{u'sequence_id': u'0', u'etag': u'0', u'type': u'folder', u'id': u'4866336745', u'name': u'imports'}
{u'sequence_id': u'0', u'etag': u'0', u'type': u'folder', u'id': u'4912855065', u'name': u'Incoming'}
{u'sequence_id': u'0', u'etag': u'0', u'type': u'folder', u'id': u'4912855189', u'name': u'Rejected'}
```

Comment: i tried indentation and other steps that were suggested for similar issue without any luck

Comment: I am returning is once outside of the loop what do you mean does it work? i believe so the results are being printed just not being put in an object for some reason

Comment: that's the exact code i am running and it works

Comment: This code has bug, because, you are returning within `inner for loop`. So after first iteration in inner for loop, your function immediately returns, so clearly the rest of inner and outer `for loop` will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to store your data to a list and return at the end. Something like this:

```
lst=[]   
for k in ids:
    print(k)
    lst.append(k)
return lst
```

But your outer loop still iterate only once, i can't really understand your code and use case, but you could use `yield` instead of `return` if you have `generator` concept and matches your use case.

Comment: dic=[]
for k in ids:
     print(k)
     dic.append(k)

Comment: but now it returns the last 2 dictionaries i still want the function to return all of the dictionaries the code is reading a list of ids and what is being printed is what is in each folder for which the id is given ie: vendor_ids